# When to update react-native version?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

what are the scenarios that require to update react native version? Will it break implemented library, How to handle break changes?

Answer (score 1):

As a good rule of thumb, most open source projects follow [this semantic versioning rules](http://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html).

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
>    Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

With this in mind, you should have an idea about what a new version brings to the table.

In spite of that, a definite answer would always be checking the release log. For react native, you can find it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases).

Comment: Have you ever upgraded react native???. if yes, what was your experiece

Comment: As most of the updates were MINOR, and thus limited in the number of breaking changes, I personally didn't encounter any problems. A big advantage of updating is that they're constantly fixing bugs and adding new features.